# Как запустить файл har через командную строку с помощью curl?

Tags: windows, api, curl

Как запустить файл har через командную строку с помощью curl?
(мой файл har состоит из авторизации на сайте с последующим включением через него моей виртуальной машины)

*Формат `HTTP Archive`, или `HAR`, представляет собой формат файла архива в формате JSON для регистрации взаимодействия веб-браузера с сайтом. Общее расширение для этих файлов `.har`.*

Comment: что такое «файл har» и каков, по вашим представлениям, должен быть результат желаемого вами «запуска»? уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format) там написаны программы, которые понимают этот формат